# Displaying images using jinja2 in the css of a tempate

Tags: css, flask, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jinja2

In a flask project, using BeautifulSoup I am using the following front-end design from codepen.io

https://codepen.io/drehimself/pen/QNXpyp

in my html template. I have a web scraped list of images and want to display them instead of the existing image using jinja2.

Notice that the images are contained in the CSS.

```
.clash-card__image {
  position: relative;
  height: 230px;
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  border-top-left-radius: $border-radius-size;
  border-top-right-radius: $border-radius-size;
}

.clash-card__image--barbarian {
  background: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/195612/barbarian-bg.jpg");
  img {
    width: 400px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -65px;
    left: -70px;
  }
}
```

Up until now, I have managed to use jinja2 to display images in the html or body part of the template.
As the images are in the CSS, I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
{% for image, title in images_titles %}
.clash-card__image--barbarian {
  background: url("{{images");
 {% endfor %}
```

I have tried various iterations of the above, but can't get the image to display. I can however, get the TITLE to display because it is in the html.

The other problem is that the list is not fixed in size. I want the cards to replicate without my having to put in the {{image}} jinja reference in each css reference.

My question is: How do I correctly put the jinja2 reference to the image in the list of images in the css?

Any best practices and suggestions also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you may be trying to use Jinja expressions in a CSS file which is included as a static asset (via a tag like `<link href='/some/file.css />`).

This won't work as these external assets are never processed by Jinja.

A quick workaround for this may be to keep this in the HTML template by including it in the `<head>` as follows:

```
<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    {% for image, title in images_titles %}
      .clash-card__image--barbarian {
        background: url("{{image}}");
      }
    {% endfor %}
  </link>
</head>
```

**EDIT:**

> what is the best practice for this as surely it is something that is often required

CSS files are, by their nature, *static*.  Modern methods of static asset deployment may put those assets on a CDN (or if using a reverse proxy like nginx have the `static` folder served by nginx, so the WSGI/app server doesn't even know about them).

With that in mind, this template probably isn't built with dynamic image URLs in mind.  On a closer inspection it appears that it's only loading a *background* image within the CSS, and the actual character image is loaded within an `<img>` tag.  So you're probably looking at two ways in which images are loaded within this template.

Since you're asking about the background image, you could change it with Javascript. Something like:

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('clash-card__image--barbarian')[0];
elem.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://localhost:5000/some_image.jpg')"
```

You could then, for example use the fetch API to load the URL string dynamically from an endpoint whtin your app.  This probably involves some more Javascript work, which is difficult to expand on within the context of this question.

---

Without Javascript, if you're placing that character image with Jinja2 syntax, perhaps doing something like:

```
<div class="clash-card__image clash-card__image--archer">
  <img src="{{image}}" />
</div>
```

You could avoid putting the CSS block in the `<head>` by modifying that parent div to load the CSS via a style tag:

```
<div style="background: url('{{bg_image}}');"
  class="clash-card__image clash-card__image--archer">
```

then remove that declaration from the external CSS file.

This has the same effect as placing the CSS within the `<head>` in the template file: it's all rendered by Jinja2 on page load.

Comment: a quick workaround, but what is the best practice for this as surely it is something that is often required ....

Comment: @MissComputing see my edit.  Hopefully this helps.  Let me know if it raises more questions than it solves :-)

Answer (score 1):

I hope my example meets your requirements. I think if you define the background images directly in the element you will save yourself a lot of trouble.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>

    <!-- All resources from Clash of Clans Cards -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css')}}" />
    <!-- End of resources from Clash of Clans Cards -->

    <style type="text/css">
      .clash-card__image {
        background-color: #1e1e1f;
        background-size: contain; /*cover or contains; decide for yourself*/
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="slide-container">
      {% for image,title in images_titles %}
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="clash-card" style="padding-bottom: 3.5rem;">
          <div class="clash-card__image" style="background-image: url({{image}});">
          </div>
          <div class="clash-card__unit-description">
            {{ title }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    (function() {

      var slideContainer = $('.slide-container');

      slideContainer.slick();

      $('.clash-card__image img').hide();
      $('.slick-active').find('.clash-card img').fadeIn(200);

      // On before slide change
      slideContainer.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
        $('.slick-active').find('.clash-card img').fadeOut(1000);
      });

      // On after slide change
      slideContainer.on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
        $('.slick-active').find('.clash-card img').fadeIn(200);
      });

    })();

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```